# Flash cs6 is there a way to play an animation from the current scene?

Tags: flash, animation, scene

I cant find anything about playing from a certain scene when i search for it so please can someone help me with this.

say i have an animation with 5 scenes, how can i preview my animation from scene 3, so it only plays scene 3,4 and 5?

its a long animation and i am sick of watching the first few scenes just to see how the last few scenes go together.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a proper way to do this, but you could temporarily add this snippet of ActionScript to the first frame of your first scene (select the frame then paste the code into the *Window / Actions* panel):

```
gotoAndPlay(1, "Scene 3");
```

Where "Scene 3" is whatever your third scene is actually named.